# CakePHP & AWS SES just stopped working

Tags: php, cakephp, amazon-web-services, cakephp-2.0, amazon-ses

I've been using AWS SES with a CakePHP app for a few months, everything was working fine but we had a server problem meaning I had take the site off and get the server restored. Once I put the site back on I noticed emails wouldn't send and causing CakePHP to error.

**The Error**

```
2013-01-14 14:50:02 Error: [SocketException] SMTP Error: 535 Incorrect authentication data
#0 /public_html/lib/Cake/Network/Email/SmtpTransport.php(132): SmtpTransport->_smtpSend('QWhRZ2F0azQyTnh...', '235')
#1 /public_html/lib/Cake/Network/Email/SmtpTransport.php(61): SmtpTransport->_auth()
#2 /public_html/lib/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php(1059): SmtpTransport->send(Object(CakeEmail))
#3 /public_html/app/Controller/UsersController.php(1945): CakeEmail->send()
```

**What I've done so far**

1. I've checked both the domain and email are verified.
2. I regenerated new SMTP details just incase they where wrong.
3. Made sure my server time was correct using NTP
4. In the meantime I set up SMTP with a google business apps.

**My Configuration (Some details altered for security)**

```
public $smtp = array(
'transport' => 'Smtp',
'from' => array('no.reply@company.com' => 'Company'),
'host' => 'ssl://email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
'port' => 465,
'timeout' => 10,
'username' => 'AKIAICH5321NNDR2CMA',
'password' => 'AhQgat12Nx21c5e78S9Ufku0+4fw9LnRpuMTGZwjXT',
'client' => null,
'log' => false,
);
```

**My Configuration for Google Business Apps (which works)**

```
public $smtp = array(
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'from' => array('no.reply@company.com' => 'Company'),
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'timeout' => 10,
    'username' => 'all@company.com',
    'password' => 'b1t306b',
    'client' => null,
    'log' => false
);
```

Could I be missing some module of my server or has AWS changed something that happened round the same time as my server change? I'd really appreciate any help or advice. Thanks Jason

Comment: Did the migration to Google Business apps change anything or are you receiving the same error(s)?

Comment: Google Business apps stops the error and emails are sending now. I would prefer to be using SES if I can get this sorted. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the issue. Under WHM there is an option SMTP Restrictions, I disabled it.
[image]